# how to get jsoup to display pictures from a website using Dreamweaver?

Tags: java, jsoup, dreamweaver, dreamweaver-templates

I'm developing a simple app where it displays pictures just like tumblr and 9gag. I couldn't exactly get it done, i hope someone can help me figure this out, i'm trying to display the pictures from eversorandom.com in a single line without a title or description.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you have tried for people to help you.

Comment: I tried using jsoup but it didn't quite work, it must be something wrong that i did, i just want a code that will display the pictures from my website (www.eversorandom.com) doesnt have to be jsoup. i'm using jquery on Dreamweaver and my knowledge is a bit limited.

Answer (score 0):

have a try at this:

add these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

here's code:

```
List<Bitmap> items = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

private class ImageGetter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            for (int i=0; i<doc.select("div.tw_post*").size(); i++) {
                // Normal size:
                String normal = doc.select("div.tw_post*").get(i).select("a").select("img").attr("src").toString());

                // Large size:
                String hiRes = doc.select("div.tw_post*").get(i).select("a").select("img").attr("data-hi-res-src").toString());

                // Decodes Normal size image:
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(normal).openStream());

                // Puts in "items" array list:
                items.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in));

                // Closes stream:
                in.close();
            }
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // what to do when some images are found
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // what to do before everything is done
    }
}
```

use in `onCreate()` method or anywhere else:

`new ImageGetter().execute("http://eversorandom.com");`

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this but i didn't get this part; use in onCreate() method or anywhere else:

new MemeGetter().execute("http://eversorandom.com");